# html <a> not clickable inside menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following menu, the `<a>`'s are not clickable, i believe it is a z-index problem but haven't been able to fix it.  Also does the html make sense, trying to make a circle with a connected rectangle on the right.  Then when it drops down it will be fully connected and filled in.  I am using bootstrap 2.3.2.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dreadjr/QJLqt/2/)

html

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span7 center"></div>
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="rightMenu visible-desktop">
            <div class="scoreBadge">--</div>
            <div class="userBadge"> <a href="/home">username ▼</a>

            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>    <a href="/settings">settings</a>

                </li>
                <li>    <a href="/logout" class="grey">log out</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.rightMenu{
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 8px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   min-width: 65px;
}
.rightMenu ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
    top: -30px;
    background-color: #4b86a1;
    color: white;
    z-index: -2;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.rightMenu ul li {
}
.rightMenu:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.rightMenu ul a {
    color: white;
}
.scoreBadge {
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    color: #4B86A1;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #fcdf05;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.userBadge {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #4b86a1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    min-width: 49px;
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    text-align: right;
    z-index: -1;
}
.userBadge > a {
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
#usrName {
    color: white;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your `css` you have

```
.rightMenu ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
    top: -18px;
    background-color: #4b86a1;
    color: white;
    z-index: -2; /* this is the problem */
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Just remove the `-` from `z-index: -2;` and it'll work. Also, without `z-index: 2;` it seems working fine, so why not just remove the `z-index` property ? An [**example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/QJLqt/3/) (with `z-index:2`) and [**another example**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/QJLqt/6/) (without `z-index` property).

Comment: the <ul> is over the other elements still, change the top to something like -30px, you will see it clearer.

Comment: Sorry! Not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: the .rightMenu ul element and css class.  Try changing the .rightMenu ul { top: -18px; } to .rightMenu ul { top: -30px; }  You will see it is over the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

I solved for you the problem see the change the z-index to 2 in the Class .rightMenu ul